# Using a select box instead of radio buttons for language selection (MVC.NET)

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I followed a tutorial for internationalization (supporting multiple languages) in an MVC .NET application. I got it all to work with the following code in Index.cshtml:

```
    @using(Html.BeginForm("SetCulture", "Home"))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Resources.ChooseYourLanguage</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <label for="nl">
                    <input name="culture" id="nl" value="nl" type="radio" @selected("nl", culture) /> Nederlands
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <label for="fr">
                    <input name="culture" id="fr" value="fr" type="radio" @selected("fr", culture) /> Français
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <label for="en">
                    <input name="culture" id="en" value="en" type="radio" @selected("en", culture) /> English
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Of course this code uses some additional scripts and such in the .cshtml file. I can provide these additional parts if needed.

I would like to use a selection menu instead of separate radio buttons. I tried the followong but it doesn't seem to do anything or react with the code to trigger language change whatsoever:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("SetCulture", "Home"))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Resources.ChooseYourLanguage</legend>
        <select class="control-group">
            <option class="controls" id="nl" value="nl" @selected("nl", culture)>Nederlands</option>
            <option class="controls" id="fr" value="fr" @selected("fr", culture)>Français</option>
            <option class="controls" id="en" value="en" @selected("en", culture)>English</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
}
```

I have no idea how to get this to work. Anyone got any tips on how I could solve this?

**EDIT:**

I just realized that I need to provide the additional code so it is fully comprehensible. So at the top of the Index.cshtml there's:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Politici Online: Hét platform om de burger dichter bij de manadataris te brengen!";
    var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLowerInvariant();
}

@helper selected(string c, string culture)
{
    if (c == culture)
    {
        @:checked="checked"
    }
}
```

And at the bottom there's the scripts section:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            $("input[type = 'radio']").click(function ()
            {
                $(this).parents("form").submit(); // post form
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
}
```

As you see the script is adapted to the use of radio buttons ... How would I change it so it has the same functionality but using a select list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you see the script is adapted to the use of radio buttons ... How
>   would I change it so it has the same functionality but using a select
>   list?

Give your `select` element an unique id and a `name` so that you can retrieve the selected value server side:

```
<select class="control-group" id="language" name="culture">
    <option class="controls" id="nl" value="nl" @selected("nl", culture)>Nederlands</option>
    <option class="controls" id="fr" value="fr" @selected("fr", culture)>Français</option>
    <option class="controls" id="en" value="en" @selected("en", culture)>English</option>
</select>
```

and then subscribe to the `.change` event and submit the parent form when the user selects another option:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            $('#language').change(function () {
                $(this).closest('form').submit(); // post form
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't seem to work. If I select another langauge in the list, something is being executed so it seems, because I do it and right after I change it switches back to the first language in the list. Any clue on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: The code I have shown in my answer will submit the parent form when the selection changes. Since you haven't shown your actual code, it's quite unclear what might be wrong with the server side code. You might try debugging your code by placing breakpoints and see what gets executed.

Comment: But it works with the radio buttons, so if I change my code according to your tips, wouldn't that mean it should basically work? I can't imagine the code needing change when the html changes. But please tell me if I'm wrong of course ;)

Comment: Yes, the code should work the same with a dropdown. Unfortunately you haven't shown your server side code and I cannot read your mind in order to tell you what might be wrong with it. Ideally you should learn to debug your code and figure it out by placing breakpoints and analyzing what exactly happens.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I'll try to find the problem using some debugging, hopefully I'll find it ;)

Comment: I just checked and, while the javascript part gets called with radio buttons, it just doesn't get called when the selection changes. The page reloads with default language because nothing changed apparently!

Comment: Did you add an `id="language"` to your `select` element as shown in my answer? Is the `.change` callback being invoked?

Comment: Yep I provided the id. I just checked again with some breakpoints, it never goes INTO the script code, but it does somehow seem to get to the @Scripts.Render every time and then reloads. I can't go any deeper apparently :s

Comment: I just debugged the underlying code (debugging .cshtml wasn't enough apprently) and found the problem. The form should call the SetCulture in HomeController, which it does, and pass a culture as a string (e.g. "en"). Problem is: no vlaue gets passed, as a result the default culture, Dutch (Nederlands), is chosen. So somehow no value gets posted in the form, any idea what I need to specifiy/ change to make this work?

Comment: Yes, you need to add a `name` attribute to your `select` element: `<select class="control-group" name="culture" id="language">`. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hmm I added the name, but still no value gets passed from the form. It should give a culture (nl, fr or en), but just gives a null string... I have no idea what is wrong, I specified the value attribute for each option in the select as you can see.

Comment: Make sure that the controller action to which you are submitting the form takes an argument with the same name.

Comment: Oh. My. God. Thaaaaank you very much!!! In the process of trying to get this to work I changed culture to language, but not in my Controller. Just changed them back to culture and BOOM it works. Thanks for your patience and great help, I appreciate it a lot!